# from an external python script call a python function which require root previlege(pynq library) is continuously crashed

Tags: python-3.x, flask, root, sudo

I have to get continuous data from a python function and one of its libraries([**Overlay**](https://pynq.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0/overlay_design_methodology/overlay_tutorial.html)) depends on root privilege. I have to run that python function by using Flask.

First of all, I have searched how to give root access to a python script but unfortunately, I haven't found any which mimic my case.

**The approach I have taken** --
1/ Python file containing **Overlay** library suppose the name is *child.py* which contains a function name `status_data`

```
from pynq import PL
from pynq import Overlay
def main_path():
    ol = Overlay("/home/xilinx/pynq/overlays/design_4/design_1_wrapper.bit")
    return ol

def status_data():
    ol = main_path()
    data = '''my_code'''
    return data
```

2/ Flask file name is *app.py* where I need the continuous data via an endpoint

```
from create_json_data import status_data
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask import jsonify
'''mayn others lib, doesn't include'''

'''my_code'''
@app.route("/auto_update_table")
def parse_auto_update_table(name=None):
    data_json = status_data()
    return jsonify(data_json)
```

3/ Both files are in the same folder. I have run that *child.py* with `sudo python3 child.py` and it works. Executed the Flask code by `sudo python3 app.py`. My guess was as *app.py* runs with `sudo` so it will take all other dependents with root privilege. But I am failed. It executes but after some moments it crashes.

Is there any workaround to call *child.py* file's `status_data` function with root privilege from *app.py* without crash? Security isn't an issue so I can reveal my credentials to any script file and if also require I can give **password manually but only once** as it is a continuous process so over and over password typing is not a tangible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. First of all, I am changing the question title as after getting the solution I have understood the present title is not fit with the situation. Though giving **root privilege** is quite easy. `sudo python3 app.py` does the work. The major flaw was in

`from pynq import Overlay`
and

```
def main_path():
    ol = Overlay("/home/xilinx/pynq/overlays/design_4/design_1_wrapper.bit")
    return ol
```

I have called this `main_path` function repeatedly but it needs a handsome amount of delay and it was absent there. So I got an unwanted crash. After declaring
`ol = Overlay("/home/xilinx/pynq/overlays/design_4/design_1_wrapper.bit")`
I have passed `ol` as a global variable to `status_data` function and it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As I know when you give admin permission (root) to an executable (your python script).
Whatever the executable does is with admin privileges. **Try with calling it with the root account itself or `sudo -u root --login "python3 app.py"` to see if it works or not**

Also saying it doesn't work is not helping. If you have a trace back. Add it to help us answer you or any more information that helps. I can't help you like this

**EDITED AFTER [user10634362](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10634362/user10634362) COMMENT BELOW**

Comment: Do you need the error displaying in the console? If **YES**, I will add it. However, I have used your suggestion but failed.
```sudo -i root python3 app.py``` and ```sudo -i root "python3 app.py"``` in both cases I have got ```-bash: root: command not found```.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo in the sudo command. It's been quite a long time I haven't worked with sudo (now running with root account). I meant the trace back you receive when you call `sudo python3 app.py`. That will help a lot

Comment: Edited the answer: use `sudo -u root --login "python3 app.py"`. Leave any trace back or error here in comments

Comment: The problem is at another point. Changed the title and given the workaround as an answer.